# installing privateinternetaccess on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I can't seem to get privateinternetaccess installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have installed openvpn (via Ubuntu software centre).

I followed PIA's suggested directions to get their portal details using :-

2. cd /etc/openvpn
3. wget https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/openvpn/openvpn.zip
4. sudo unzip openvpn.zip (sudo apt-get install unzip <-- may be required first)
5. ls -l    (see a list of the server config files)

The result was a SINGLE script file update-resolv-conf in /etc/openvpn.

That's as far as I can get, network-manager doesn't get me anywhere & if I try sudo openvpn 'update-resolv-conf" I get config errors.

As you can see, I am LOST, can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using their service with a Desktop it's rather easy.
They have an `install_ubuntu.sh` script for 12 LTS that works with 14 LTS.

Simply download to your computer
then navigate to the script you downloaded in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>):

```
cd /home/YOUR_USERNAME/Downloads/
```

then run the script

```
./install_ubuntu.sh
```

You will have to type in your user name provided from private internet access.com

And it should set up the service.

All you do to activate is click on the top right icon for your internet connection (could be 2 arrows for Ethernet connections or WiFi bars for WiFi connection) then hover over VPN,

Select the VPN server you'd like to tunnel to, then all should be functioning.

Sorry for the quick response, Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you only installed one of a few things you need. Follow PIA's instructions for Ubuntu 12.04 to the later:

- Install these packages.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  ```
- Add a new OpenVPN connection.
- Select a host from their network page.
- You want to create a Password connection.
- I created a folder in Home: "VPN" and extracted the ca.crt file
  there. That's the file you use for the CA certificate: ca.crt
- In the Advanced check "Use LZO data compression".